# Technology choice for a service that .NET 2.0 clients will consume

Tags: .net-2.0

I am trying to decide which technology to use to implement a service that will be consumed by .NET 2.0 clients.

The client needs to be able to request a set of files.  The request will consist of filename and version.  The number of files a client may request can vary.

The clients must not be expcted to support .NET above version 2.0.

The service will stream the requested set of files as a single compressed archive.

I am somewhat baffled regarding the choices I have in which to implement the service and (more importantly) how to consume the service from .NET 2.0.  It's been a long time since I wrote .NET 2.0 code and I'm not sure how to consume any of the technologies I have been reading about from .NET 2.0 code.

I believe my options with regards to technology are:

1. ASMX web services
2. WCF with basicHttpBinding
3. WCF Web HTTP (using WebInvoke with POST, I believe I can stream data up in a HttpWebRequest object)?
4. Some kind of REST service?
5. Other?

Which of the above are viable for .NET 2.0 clients?

How can I pass my set of filename/version mappings to from .NET 2.0 code?

I don't need exact code; just a general recommendation for the service technology and a general idea of how to pass my data up.  I can research the rest myself.

Answer (score 0):

only ASMX web services is available in .Net 2.0

Comment: Are you sure that is accurate?  It is only my clients that are constrained to .NET 2.0.  I have created a test .NET 2.0 client already that can consume a .NET 3.5 WCF service with a webHttpBinding endpoint.  For the test I used WebGet i.e. passing parameters in the URL.  This isn't any use to me because I need to be able to pass a larger amounts of data that can be supported via the query string.